# running ECDH with CommonCrypto for iOS

Tags: cryptography, ios

I am looking for the methods in CommonCrypto to generate the shared secret based on ECDH. I can find proprietary implementations but nothing standard. This method is called sometimes Key Exchange and includes the calculation of the shared secret. Can someone send a link to the right documentation or to an example that uses CommonCrypto for generating the shared secret based on Elliptic curve Diffie–Hellman?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CommonCrypto implements ECDH. Apple Open Source includes the [source code for the implementation](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/CommonCrypto/CommonCrypto-60026/Source/API/CommonECCryptor.c). The problem is that the implementation is not exposed in the iOS SDK header files. I just checked iOS SDK versions 6.1 and 8.0, and the functions are not declared. This means that any app that somehow calls the routines will violate [Apple's App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/): Section 2.5 says "Apps that use non-public APIs will be rejected".

I suggest using OpenSSL, which includes ECDH.

Comment: Seems like it is Open Source, so you should also be able to recompile the ECDH functionality (?). Of course using a precompiled package is easier.